# java SWT transparent composite background

Tags: java, swt

i have composite object

```
Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
composite.setBounds(new Rectangle(10,10,100,100);
```

How do i make this composite to have transparent background?

I will need to have widgets(non transparent) placed in this composite...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That not possible to create a `Composite` with transparent background. You can use a `Shell` with a transparent background (see [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTShellcreateanonrectangularwindow.htm)), and put widgets inside it.