# Set background image for composite, such that the inner composite does not show background

Tags: java, swt

I have a main composite and inside it another composite, now i want to set background image for the outer composite , when i do that the inner composite shows a white background how to get rid of that white background?

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite outer = new Composite(parent, SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
    outer.setBackgroundImage(new Image(null , this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("background.jpg")));

    Composite inner = new Composite(outer, SWT.NONE);
    //add text, label etc to inner
}
```

The background is set but only for the inner composite white background apears.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to make your code example a little more comprehensive and non-environment-specific. To compile your code, I would have to do a lot more work, and supply a "background.jpg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SWT.INHERIT_FORCE` is not supposed to be passed to constructor. Instead, call

```
outer.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martti Kaarik. You are a life saver ! It works for background color also !! I was manually doing it for all its child composite ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to put something over your outer `Composite` that has a background image.

Either you try setting `inner.setBackground(null)`, or you manually draw with `GC` whatever you want to draw on that background image, then eliminate the "inner" `Composite`.
[Also check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542524/java-swt-transparent-composite-background)

[DO **NOT** FORGET TO DISPOSE YOUR IMAGES](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Image%20lifecycle) !! Rookie's mistake.